# Chrome Extension: Javascript not working in chrome.window.create panel

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have an external app which I'm trying to load into a `chrome.window` `panel`. Kind of like Google Hangouts Chrome extension.

Problem is that the `panel` doesn't run any of the javascript. If I change the type of the chrome.window to `popup`everything works fine.

What could be the problem?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Here is the code I run in my background.js

```
chrome.windows.create({url: "https://myapp.com", type: 'panel'});
```

If I change this to:

```
chrome.windows.create({url: "https://myapp.com", type: 'popup'});
```

The javascript located at https://myapp.com works great but not when the `type` is set to `panel`.

And here is the code I'm running on mayapp.com:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready( function() {
   alert('Running jQuery...');
});
</script>
```

Comment: The problem could be that we are not seeing any code...

Comment: LOL - I was rather referring to that mysterious, non-working JS code in `https://yourapp.com`.

Comment: Don't see the purpose of showing you the code as the code works in a regular browser window and a popup. But I have updated the question with the code as well.

Comment: It's a funny thing to say: I have some code that does not work, but I am not showing you the code. Do you have any idea why ? Unless you imply that there is something wrong with panels that prevents JS code from executing altogether, then there is high probability that the problem/issue has its root in the code itself. BTW, have you enabled panels in your Chrome ?

Comment: Agreed! Yes I have enabled panels so the panel shows but no alert. I did chrome://flags/#enable-panels when I enabled panels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not really sure why (so someone more knowledgable could shed some light on this), but some "web features" are disabled in panel-windows. It may be for security reasons or due to the fact that the underlying OS is responsible for the UI (I am just speculating here).

Those features include *JavaScript Popup Boxes* (i.e. `alert`, `confirm`, `prompt`).
So, your jQuery is working fine, e.g. try replacing your listener with:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
     $(document.body).text('Running jQuery...');
});
```

---

<sub>I don't know if this is related, but the same holds for **[Chrome Packaged Apps](http://developer.chrome.com/apps)**. This is a list of **[Disabled Web Features](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_deprecated.html)** in apps.

I am not implying the same features are disabled on panels as well, I merely provide this as a *hint*.</sub>

Comment: Great thanks! Do you know if panels support feature to access microphone like pop-ups and regular windows do? This will eventually find its way into my app so just wondering if you know anything about that?

Comment: I don't really know. If I had to guess, I would say Flash is probably out of question, but HTML5 APIs whould be good-to-go. (But again I am just guessing.) BTW, don't forget to accept/upvote the answer if you found it helpful :)